# Algebra proof using Lagrange

Tags: abstract-algebra

So I am asked to proof the following

If p is a prime and b is a non zero element of the field $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$.

Show that $b^{p-1}=1$

The hint is Lagrange.

I didn't proof it, but I think I should start by noting that.

Since $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is a field all of its non zero elements have multiplicative inverse. And then somehow I should connect what I know about fields, and Lagranges theorem which states that the order of a subgroup divides the order of the Group. But I am not sure how to connect it

Comment: Which group do you think we're talking about, and what is its order?

Comment: we're talking about $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ and it has prime order, not sure about ''what Group it is''?

Comment: What's the group operation in that group?

Comment: multiplication operation?

Comment: Then how does $0$ fit into this group structure? What is its inverse? (Hint: the relevant group in this case contains all elements _except_ $0$.)

Comment: True, since the element b is a non zero element of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ then $\forall$ b there exists a w s.t. bw=1. hence $b=w^{-1}$.

Comment: And since $\Bbb Z_p$ has order $p$, and we took away the element $0$, this group has order ... That means that by Lagrange, the order of $b$ divides ... Therefore $b^{p-1} =$ ...

Comment: for your first ... $a^p=e$, $\implies |G|=p$

Comment: for your second ... The order of b divides p? by lagrange

Comment: You didn't answer my _first_ question. How many elements are there in this multiplicative group if $\Bbb Z_p$ has $p$ elements, and we've removed $0$?

Comment: there should be p-1 elements

Comment: Yup. And by Lagrange, that means that the order of $b$ divides ... And this means that $b^{p-1}$ equals ...

Comment: but to use lagrange shouldn't b be a subgroup?

Comment: $b$ isn't a subgroup. But $\langle b \rangle$, the cyclic group generated by $b$, is a subgroup. And the order of $b$ is the same as the order of $\langle b\rangle$.

Comment: so $p-1/p-1=1$ ?

Comment: That is true, but irrelevant. The order of $\langle b\rangle$ divides $p-1$ by Lagrange's theorem, which means that the order of $b$, which is the same number, also divides $p-1$. Let's say the order of $b$ is $n$, with $nk = p-1$. Then $b^{p-1} = b^{nk} = (b^n)^k = 1^k = 1$, and that's the end of the proof.

Comment: Okay thank you very much for your patience :), I will study your last argument